# How to get Authorization token for Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to integrate Google cloud storage API for transferring all my web app uploads to google cloud storage.

According to documentation, I need to pass Authorization header every time making a new request but am not getting where I can get that Authorization token? I tried so hard I checked a lot of Git repos and StackOverflow discussions.

Still am not able to find answers.

For more [information](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication#apiauth):

[image: A screenshot of the aforementioned documentation for listing objects on Google Cloud.]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the Authorization token in [OAuth 2.0 Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/). Follow the steps described. Notice that in step 2 you have to click on “Exchange authorization code for tokens” to obtain the “Access token” you need. I suggest you to follow this [Uploading objects](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects) guide (REST APIs) the first time you try it.

Perhaps you can do this using the [Cloud Storage Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-python).

Comment: Ruben this token expires in one hour. How we can make the permanent token?

Comment: @HassanRaza Use "Refresh Tokens" to get new authorization tokens in backend.