# Firebase storage API - upload file with metada

Tags: javascript, firebase, rest, blob, firebase-storage

I am using the rest api to upload files to firebase storage as described in the following answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/65462416/8634683.

And I would like to set the **cache-control metadata** but can't figure it out.

I found the next firebase doc - https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/file-metadata
but didn't saw any information about the rest API.

=== Update ====

So I did a little bit of reverse engineering, , and I found that when I am using the JS-SDK, the library add a prefix to the file, Any one know what is the meaning of the first long number?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

So I found the answer:

Send the blob file with a prefix and suffix as follow:

```
let prefix = `
--23483860318350978727016216849495
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="metadata"

{"name":"${filePath}", "cacheControl":"max-age=7200","contentType":"${fileType}"}
                
--23483860318350978727016216849495
Content-Type: ${fileType}`

let suffix = '\n--23483860318350978727016216849495--'

let blobWithMetadata = new Blob([prefix, blob, suffix])
```

and add the following headers:

```
headers = { 
  'x-goog-upload-protocol': 'multipart',
  'content-type': 'multipart/related; boundary=23483860318350978727016216849495'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to make an additional call but use `patch` method instead of `post` and submit the metadata as json in the body.